# How to remove an icon from Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I installed DbVisualize in Ubuntu 12.04. Now I don't want to use it anymore, so I deleted the folder "DBVisualizer" in my Home folder. Problem is I can still see the icon in the Dash.

How could I remove it completely from my system (for other apps too)?

Comment: uninstalling software usually cannot be done by deleting a folder. it depends how u installed it. so plz specify how the install has been done then can someone help you

Comment: I run a "sh" file to install the software. So I thought I could uninstall it by deleting the folder.

Comment: there would also be an uninstall.sh (most prob there is one) in the same folder.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Dash picks up its entries from .desktop files placed in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`.

Deleting the .desktop file corresponding to your program should remove its entry from Dash.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, this seems to be quite a common problem. Ubuntu should include a MENU editor by default.

First I uninstalled the application, then I deleted all references from the following folder:

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
```

Rebooted....but never resolved my issue.

So installed this MENU editor:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caldas-lopes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ezame
```

and delete unwanted icons.

Comment: `/usr/local/share/applications` is exactly what I was looking for when I stumbled across your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should delete programs through Synaptic or Software center, but not simple by deleting the application folder.
Also, you can delete the application icon from the unity dashboard by right-clicking it and than clicking on the "Unlock from Launcher".